# Any built-in function in Oracle to round down numbers and distribute the remaining values randomly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table say STAFF that stores the staff names and their salaries.
Below are some sample data:

```
STAFF        | SALARY
===========================
ALEX         | 100.4
JESSICA      | 100.4
PETER        | 99.2
```

The total of salaries is always a whole number and I want to round down all staff's salaries and then randomly put the remaining value to one of them.

For example, the output would be like below if JESSICA is selected to receive the remaining value.

```
STAFF        | SALARY
===========================
ALEX         | 100
JESSICA      | 101
PETER        | 99
```

Does Oracle provide any built-in function to perform the described operation.

Comment: you meant to write select query or table insert ?

Comment: select query is ok as I can insert the select results to another table afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity `SALARY - TRUNC(SALARY)` should give the decimal portion of each salary, for each record.  You can sum this for the entire table, and then increment a certain user's salary but this amount.  Try something like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET SALARY = TRUNC(SALARY) + (SELECT SUM(SALARY - TRUNC(SALARY)) FROM yourTable)
WHERE STAFF = 'JESSICA'
```

Comment: Or `TRUNC(SALARY) + (SELECT SUM(SALARY - TRUNC(SALARY)) FROM yourTable)` which looks slightly more semantically correct (mathematically it does not matter indeed).

Answer (score 0):

here I have tried one thing that gives random result based on generated random no.

```
 with mine(STAFF,salary,status) as
  (
    select 'ALEX',100.4,'Y' from dual union all
    select 'JESSICA',100.4,'Y' from dual union all
    select 'PETER',99.2,'Y' from dual union all
    select 'randomno',floor(dbms_random.value(1,4)),'N' vno from dual
  )
  select STAFF,decode(rndno,rno,csalary,rsalary) salary,decode(rndno,rno,'selected to receive the remaining value',null) selected from(
  select rownum rno,STAFF,salary,round(salary) rsalary,ceil(salary) csalary,
  (select salary from mine where status='N') rndno
   from mine where status='Y'
);
```

here on every run on query new user is selected which have floating salary.
in above query i have add one onther rows that supply random no and compare with acual result rows.